# How to check-in annotated tags?

Tags: git, github, tagging

Our project recently moved from Sourceforge to GitHub. The migration did not include the subversion tags. I have very little Git skill, so I used [2.6 Git Basics - Tagging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) as a guide.

I performed a Git checkout:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp.git cryptopp-git
```

I then went through and reproduced the tags for the last 15 years or so using:

```
# Produce a log file
$ git log --all --oneline > git.log

# Look for the subversion commit (yes; it was a CVS migration 15 or so years ago):
$ awk 'NR==(872-3)' git.log 
bf7ae38 This commit was manufactured by cvs2svn to create tag 'CRYPTOPP_5_0'.

# Tag it:
$ git tag -a CRYPTOPP_5_0 bf7ae38
[Add message in emacs]

# Lather, rinse, repeat
...
```

Next, I tried to commit them:

```
$ git commit -m "Rebuild tags after GitHub import"
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ git push
Everything up-to-date
```

So I went to another machine to verify the work. I performed a `git pull` (Debian 8 Chroot on a distinct machine):

```
# git pull
Already up-to-date.

# git show CRYPTOPP_5_0
fatal: ambiguous argument 'CRYPTOPP_5_0': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

The best I can tell, the information has not been checked-in to GitHub.

How, exactly, do I check-in the tags to GitHub?

Comment: Future visitors... It appears you can change the date associated with a tag. We found the tag was dated with the date of the commit (which was not quite correct after a GitHub migration), and not the date of the release (which would have happened some time in the past). See [`GIT_COMMITTER_DATE`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `--tags` option of `git push`. This will push your tags to the remote.

```
git push --tags
```

Note that this is not a feature of GitHub, but normal `git` behaviour. Also have a look at [the git push man page](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=git-push&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+8+jessie&format=html&locale=en).